Problem with Python subprogram popen and run
I was trying to experiment with processes in Python, and am running into a situation that doesn't seem to make sense.
My first Python program is:
import subprocess;

print('Main running!')

subprocess.run("Notepad.exe")

print('Main program exiting')

My second Python program is:
import subprocess;

print('Main running!')

subprocess.Popen("Notepad.exe")

print('Main program exiting')


If I start by running program #1, it does what I expect - Wait for me to close Notepad and exits
If I next run program #2, it also does what I expect - Exit immediately without waiting for Notepad to close
Now if I run program #1 again, the Python program exits immediately, even if Notepad is still open.

Am I missing something?
